# Increment the font size of entire html document(all element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I am making a large website using html/css. I changed my font to Josephin Sans and all the text now appear smaller. Is there a way to increment font size of all elements(i.e. 12px becomes 13px, 14px becomes 15px, 20px becomes 21px, so on).

There are way too many elements, so it is not possible to do individually for each element.

Comment: You should have used rems to avoid such problems

Comment: If you use , rem,% or em for your font-size, then resetting the font-size value on html will do it. If you used pixels, you'll have to go through each to update value and unit to avoid this again :) Your editor should have a function to look for strings and replace them. exemple search for 12px and replace it with 0.75em ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
function incrAllFontSize(){
  $("*").each(function(index, elem){
    var $this = $(this);//caching for perf. opt.

    var curr = $this.css("fontSize");//get the fontSize string
    if(curr != "" && curr != undefined){//check if it exist
      curr = curr.replace(/px$/, "");//get rid of "px" in the string

      var float_curr = parseFloat(curr);//convert string to float
      float_curr += 1;//actual incr

      var new_val = "" + float_curr + "px";//back to string
      $this.css("fontSize", new_val);//set the fontSize string
    }
  });
}
```

And :

```
$(document).ready(incrAllFontSize);
```

EDIT
I completely forgot to mention that this uses jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

12px is 12px is 12px. You can't really redefine how big 12px is with a css attribute. What you can do, however, if replace your pixel values with ems. Generally speaking, 1em = 16px, so you can do the math with how many ems to replace each pixel value with.

When everything is set up in ems, you can set parent elements as a sort-of multiplier for the ems for the children. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/620omjfs/) for you to help demonstrate this point.

HTML:

```
<div class="xs">Extra Small text</div>
<div class="s">Small text</div>
<div class="m">Medium text</div>
<div class="l">Large text</div>
<div class="xl">Extra Large text</div>

<button class="toggle">
Toggle
</button>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

body.large {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.xs {
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

.s {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.m {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

.l {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.xl {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

JavaScript (for simply toggling the class):

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass('large');
});
```